# Why isn't this wiring working?

Tags: terraria-mobile

[image]

In Terraria, I've just finished creating this wiring, which doesn't seem to work. I turned it on, and nothing is happening, so I'd appreciate some help with my issue.

Comment: Which wiring, the active block 'door' on the character's left, or the goblin statue on the right? [Goblin statues are purely decorative](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Goblin_Statue) - they don't produce goblins when activated.

Comment: Your question is flawed, do you mean the Goblin statue (Which as said below won't do anything) or the door. Also, try to give more insight into the problem you have, rather than just, "Why isn't this [] working?!"

Answer (score 7):

Goblin statues are purely decorative - wiring up one to a timer will not cause it to spawn goblins. In fact, most statues are not functional at all.

The Terraria wiki has [a list of statues that do spawn monsters](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Statues#Monster_Spawning_Statues) when activated:

- Fish (Goldfish)
- Bird
- Bunny
- Chest (Mimic)
- Skeleton
- Crab
- Jellyfish
- Slime
- Piranha
- Shark

In addition, [the bomb, heart and star statue spawns their respective items when activated](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Statues#Item_Spawning_Statues), and [the King and Queen statues function as teleporters for bringing NPCs to the statue's location.](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Statues#Function_Statues)

Comment: And worth noting is that the Mimic statue doesn't drop normal Mimic loots. For money making and useful items, farming bombs and slimes off Slimes and Glowsticks/necklaces from Jellyfish would be your best bet.

Comment: Alternatively, for money making, using a lucky coin and a Slime Staff (preferably broken), you can spawn statue enemies and let the staff do all the work. Money will drop constantly as the enemies stack and the slime attacks.